# How to set up a private network with nested routers to ssh intou from the outside

Tags: networking, router, ssh

I have four Pi's connected to a router behind an ADSL modem (with a static ip), that connects to the internet.

[image]

What settings should I use on my ADSL modem and router to successfully ssh from the outside into each of the Pies on my private network?

Previously I've successfully set up port forwarding on the ADSL router, when Pi was connected straight to it, ssh'ed fine! But now I have a nested router. What should my next steps be?

Comment: Why do you have a nested router, what is the benefit? Also, what are the addresses of your router, you show only one address.

Comment: Each pi needs to have the service port of the SSH dameon changed to a unique port number. I.e pi-1= 2200 pi-2 = 2201 pi-3 = 2202 etc. Because you have the routers cascaded you will have your port forward twice... Consider bridging the two routers.